# How to setup the same Django Virtual Environemnt in two computers?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

currently I need to setup a production Django app in my computer and I would like to know what's the best way to do it? The production server uses virtualenv and I executed the following commands to get some info about the environment. Thanks

```
$ uname -a
Linux domU-12-31-39-0C-75-E2 2.6.34.7-56.40.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 22 18:48:49 UTC 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ pwd
/home/ec2-user/virtenvs/django-1.2.5/

$ ./pip freeze
Cheetah==2.4.1
Django==1.2.5
M2Crypto==0.20.2
Markdown==2.0.1
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PIL==1.1.7
PyYAML==3.05
Pygments==1.1.1
South==0.7.3
boto==2.0b4
cloud-init==0.5.15
configobj==4.6.0
distribute==0.6.10
django-classy-tags==0.3.3
django-cms==2.1.3
django-haystack==1.1.0
django-tinymce==1.5.1a1
iniparse==0.3.1
policycoreutils-default-encoding==0.1
pycurl==7.19.0
pygeoip==0.1.5
pygpgme==0.1
pysolr==2.0.13
pysqlite==2.6.0
python-Levenshtein==0.10.2
pytz==2011c
pywurfl==7.2.1
setools==1.0
urlgrabber==3.9.1
virtualenv==1.5.1
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this on the current server:

```
pip freeze -l > requirements.txt
```

Then this on other machines:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

There are related [pip docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) online which describe the functionality.

Comment: Thank you! Very good tip for getting the version requirements of installed python eggs and packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the code open-sourced and able to be developed with others/on other computers... You could use git or mercurial.

http://git-scm.com/ is the homepage for git,

https://github.com/ is the site for storing git repositories, allowing for "social" coding as they describe it, which is explained at...

http://gitready.com/, which teaches you how to use git.

Comment: In general this approach is good practice, but it doesn't address the problem that the original poster has with dependencies.